# cursor position issue in activity

Tags: android

I have created one activity i.e loginpage. it contains some edit textboxes, when I run the application the cursor is defaultly going to last edit text field. My requirement is cursor should be defaultly in first edit text field.

Comment: I dont think so this should happen.can you show your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EditText yourEdittext1=(EditText)findview...();
EditText yourEdittext2=(EditText)findview...();

yourEdittext1.requestFocus();
```